# how to change the particular variable value in hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following `initialState`:

```
 const intialFormState = {
        age: "",
        multiline: "",
        currency: "",
        name: "",
        firstName: "",
        lastName: "",
        phone: "",
        email: "",
        city: "",
        country: "",
        gender: "",
        password: "",
        check1: "",
        check2: "",
        check3: "",
        skills: [],
        edit: false,
        userid: "",
        touched: {
          name: false,
          phone: false,
          email: false
        }
      };
      const [user, setUser] = useState(intialFormState);
```

And I would like to know how to change only `check1`, `check2` and `check3` values

Comment: That is not possible with `useState`

Answer (score 1):

Just `spread` the original object and replace the `properties` you want

```
const changeCheck1 = () => ({
    ...initialFormState,
    check1: 'foo'
})

const result = changeCheck1()
setUser(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to access through setUser, but be aware that with hooks what you pass to setUser will be just copied into user.

So in order to only update a certain field you have to perform a copy of the original state, update only the fields that you want and then call the set method with the updated object

Answer (score 0):

you can do it a lot of ways, please refer: [this link](https://medium.com/recraftrelic/usestate-and-useeffect-explained-cdb5dc252baf):

```
        const newUser = {...user, check1: true, check2: false, check3: true};
        setUser(newUser);
```

or

```
       setUser({check1: true, check2: false, check3: true});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite similar to old-fashioned `setState` with previous value as param, If you want to update only a particular field without affecting other fields, here is how to do it

```
// Change check 1 value without affect the other
setUser((prevUser) => ({
  ...prevUser,
  check1: 'some_value'
}));
```